# How does one cleanup Flink stream state for inactive keys?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

My goal is to have a Flink streaming program that keeps the last N ids, where the id is extracted from an event. The sink is a Cassandra store so that the list of ids can be fetched at any time. It is important that Cassandra is updated immediately upon every event.

This can be implemented easily with `mapWithState` (see code below). However, there is important problem with this code. The state is keyed by `userid`. Some users might be active for some time and then never again. What I am worrying about is that state storage will grow forever.

How does one cleanup state for inactive keys?

```
case class MyEvent(userId: Int, id: String)

env
  .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer010[MyEvent]("vips", new MyJsonDeserializationSchema(), kafkaConsumerProperties))
  .keyBy(_.userId)
  .mapWithState[(Int, Seq[String]), Seq[String]] { (in: MyEvent, currentIds: Option[Seq[String]]) =>
    val keepNIds = currentIds match {
      case None => Seq(in.id)
      case Some(cids) => (cids :+ in.id).takeRight(100)
    }
    ((in.userId, keepNIds), Some(keepNIds))
  }
  .addSink { in: (Int, Seq[String]) =>
    CassandraSink.appDatabase.idsTable.store(...)
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The growing state is an important and correct observation. This will definitely happen if your keyspace is moving.

Flink 1.2.0 added the `ProcessFunction` which addresses this problem. A `ProcessFunction` is similar to a `FlatMapFunction` but has access to timer services. You can register timers which invoke the `onTimer()` callback function when they expire. The callback can be used to clean-up the state.

Comment: Thanks, now I found `RichProcessFunction` and I can register call backs with code like `ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(expiryMillis)`. We want to keep this data around for a long time, 30 days for now. Meanwhile there will be billions of additional callbacks. Can Flink handle this massive number of callbacks?

Comment: Timers are hold in state and checkpointed. I think it should be possible, but I recommend to test this under some load.

Comment: I found a way to limit the number of timers to 1 per key: `processElement` only starts a timer for new keys and `onTimer` schedules again when the latest and current state does not have to be expired yet. Now we'll only get a few dozen million of active timers. I hope that will work :)

Comment: hi @ErikvanOosten, would you mind giving more information of how you did it? Or share a bit of code? please. I'm trying to do something similar but without much success so far.

Comment: @ErikvanOosten I second this, can you please give us some more info